# In c#, list collection manipulation with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the method

```
public void selectValue(List<VolumeName> volumeNames)
{
  List<IVolumeImage> VolumeImages = _recoveryPointsProvider.SelectMany(rp => rp.VolumeImages).ToList();

  List<IVolumeImage> volumeImagesExceptVolumeNames = ?
}
```

`IVolumeImage` has a property `VolumeName`

```
VolumeName VolumeName { get; }
```

How to select collection of IVolumeImage except volumes that have names `volumeNames`?

Comment: See duplicate. `Where(v => !volumeNames.Contains(v.VolumeName))`.

Answer (score 0):

You should return items that do not have their name among the names of the `volumeNames` collection:

```
List<IVolumeImage> volumeImagesExceptVolumeNames = VolumeImages.Where(o => !volumeNames.Exists(v => v.VolumeName == o.VolumeName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

var volumeImagesExceptVolumeName = VolumeImages.where(v=> !(volumeName.Contains(v.VolumeName))).ToList()